# Extjs LabelAlign=top is not working in panel

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I want to display the label on top of text field, but it is not displaying. Below is the code.(in fact the below code displays the label at the right side of text field).I am using extjs 3.4, note :  Using form panel is also not working as expected (have pasted the code below)

Any help is much appreciated.

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
    var contentsPanel = new Ext.Panel({
        labelAlign: 'top',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        layout: 'form',
        defaultType: 'textfield',

        items: [{
            fieldLabel: 'First Name',
            name: 'first'
        }]
    });
    contentsPanel.show();
});   

Ext.onReady(function () {
    var contentsPanel = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        defaultType: 'textfield',
        labelAlign: 'top',
        items: [{
            fieldLabel: 'First Name',
            name: 'first',
            labelAlign: 'top'
        }]
    });
    contentsPanel.show();
});
```

Comment: Do you want to display label above text field?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what i want.

Comment: Okay. Please change the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

labelAlign is a property of field, not panel property. Need to configure field:

```
items:[{
    fieldLabel: 'FirstName',
    labelAlign: 'top',
    name: 'first'
}]
```

If you want set labelAlign for all panel fields, you can add in panel config:

```
var contentsPanel = new Ext.Panel({
    fieldDefaults: {
        labelAlign: 'top'
    },
    ...
```

Comment: Hi Vlad,Thanks for your rely. i tried that,but i still the label is not appearing on top of text field. (i tried using Formpanel instead of panel as Formpanel has labelAlign property but with that also it is not working.

Comment: @Kalai See example with Ext 3.4 in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dZktz/ Also you can see examples for ExtJs 3 on Sencha site: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/examples/form/dynamic.html

Comment: @ Vlad, Thank you very much, things are working fine. Actually the problem was in our product somewhere there is a custom style for .x-form-label-top which caused the issue. Thanks once again.